# Finding the most similar node by their shared child nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to find a node which would be the most similar to another one by the child nodes they both share and then list those nodes they share.

For example I have:

```
N1-[has]->A
N1-[has]->B
N1-[has]->C
N1-[has]->D

N2-[has]->A
N2-[has]->B
N2-[has]->E
N2-[has]->F

N3-[has]->A
N3-[has]->B
N3-[has]->C
N3-[has]->G
```

So then I want to check which node is the most similar by it's child nodes to N1.
It should be N3 because they share 3 child nodes

Now i can find which node it is by using

```
match (n1:Node {name: "some name"})-[:HAS]->(i)<-[:HAS]-(n2:Node) 
with n2.name as n, count(*) as c 
return n order by c desc limit 1
```

But I need the list of the nodes they share, I have been sitting on this for quite some time and can not get my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using [collect()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/aggregating/#functions-collect) to store similar nodes into a collection and then return it:

```
match (n1:Node {name: "some name"})-[:HAS]->(i)<-[:HAS]-(n2:Node) 
with n2.name as n, collect(i) as similarNodes, count(*) as c 
return n, similarNodes
order by c desc limit 1
```

Comment: You are welcome! Thank you for accepting the answer. @SteelShot